# Regex that matches '1-length non-digit'

Tags: regex

I'm doing some data imports, and `T-SQL`'s `IS_NUMERIC` test returns true for `+`, `-` and currency symbol characters. I need a check to cancel these out as well.

How can I match a single character that is not a number? The whole string length must be one in that case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would be `\D`.

If I remember correctly, regexes in T-SQL are automatically anchored to the start and end of the string.

If not, use `^\D$`.

Comment: If \D comes up as invalid syntax (which it may do, depending on which 'flavour' of regex you're using), an alternative would be to use [^0-9]